# Custom grant type implementation

Tags: keycloak

I have to request jwtoken with custom way of validating whether the client is authenticated or not. So basically i need to call token endpoint with custom grant type:

`openid-connect/token`

with scope: my_scope 
grant_type: custom_grant_type, client_id: my_client_id, client_secret: my_client_secret, organization_id: some_organization

The difference is that the client_secret and organization_id will validated by external service so I need to do a call to that service to make sure those values are proper.

I thought I could make use of `ClientAuthenticatorFactory` and `ClientAuthenticator` and implement all the necessarry logic here however after the successfull registration of that classes within keycloak server, I still cannot chose that from clients. My plugin is visible via Authentication menu. When I go to flow details, there is my custom implementation registered but, how do I use it within my client?

What should I implement to being able to add custom oidc grant_type?